# I have multiple text blocks that will be filled with numbers. I need them to totaled up together and then put into another text block

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, textblock

I am creating a golfing app. It is a 9 hole golf course. I created a page that has 9 separate text blocks that the user can enter in their score for each hole. Then I have a textbox that I want the final score to be put in. I know how to do this if I put a button to just add up all of the scores at the end, but what I am trying to get it to do, is to add them up once the score is put in. So when the user enters in their first score, the total box will put that one in it, then when the second score is put in its respective box, I want it to add that score to the total etc... for all 9 blocks.

I am creating this as a Windows Phone App with C#

```
private void Calculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    int x1 = int.Parse(textBox1.Text); 
    int x2 = int.Parse(textBox2.Text); 
    int x3 = int.Parse(textBox3.Text); 
    int x4 = int.Parse(textBox4.Text); 
    int x5 = int.Parse(textBox5.Text); 
    int x6 = int.Parse(textBox6.Text); 
    int x7 = int.Parse(textBox7.Text); 
    int x8 = int.Parse(textBox8.Text); 
    int x9 = int.Parse(textBox9.Text); 
    int total = x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9; 
    TotalBlock.Text = total.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: private void Calculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            int x1=int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            int x2=int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            int x3 = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
            int x4 = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
            int x5 = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
            int x6 = int.Parse(textBox6.Text);
            int x7 = int.Parse(textBox7.Text);
            int x8 = int.Parse(textBox8.Text);
            int x9 = int.Parse(textBox9.Text);
            int total = x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9;
            TotalBlock.Text = total.ToString();

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to this website. I didn't know how to put it in code form. But that is how I have it set up if the person types in all of his/her scores and the presses a button. But what I'm trying to do is to have a text box change immediately when someone enters in a new number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    textBlock1.OnTextChanged += textChanged();
    textBlock2.OnTextChanged += textChanged();
    ...
    textBlock9.OnTextChanged += textChanged();

    public void textChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
        int result = Convert.ToInt32(textBlock1.Text) + ... + Convert.ToInt32(textBlock9.Text);
        finalTextBlock.Text = result.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I tried that but it keeps giving me the error, Method must have a return type.

Comment: Try to change the method textChanged as I did in my edited code.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your `TextBlock`'s in an array first, this becomes a lot simpler:

```
private TextBlock[] numberTextBlocks;

// Call this method at some point while setting up your UI
private void Initialize()
{
    this.numberTextBlocks = new TextBlock[] 
    {
         textBlock1, textBlock2, ...
    };

    foreach(t in this.numberTextBlocks)
    {
        t.OnTextChanged += NumberTextBlock_OnTextChanged;
    }
}

private void NumberTextBlock_OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.RecalculateTotal();
}

private void Calculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    this.RecalculateTotal();
}

private void RecalculateTotal(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    int total = this.numberTextBlocks.Sum(t => int.Parse(t.Text));
    TotalBlock.Text = total.ToString();
}
```